# Svelte: Set focus to slotted element in custom web component

Tags: focus, web-component, shadow-dom, svelte, slot

I'm currently building a custom web components library using Svelte.

I have finished a select-options dropdown component, which can accept nested, slotted content to comprise the dropdown options. It works without any known issues for mouse users and would be implemented like so:

```
<custom-select label="My Custom Select Element">
        <custom-option value="1">Option 1</custom-option>
        <custom-option value="2">Option 2</custom-option>
        <custom-option value="3">Option 3</custom-option>
</custom-select>
```

I am now working on the accessibility of the component, and need to implement a "trap focus". Without getting into the various ways to implement a trap focus, I am trying to complete a simple test of assigning focus to one of the slotted elements from within the parent component. The slotted elements all have tabindex="0" and I am able to tab through them without issue.

I can successfully "grab" the element I want to focus using bindings in Svelte. While you cannot place a binding directive directly on the slot element (you *can* place attributes on slot), I was able to bind to a parent span tag like so:

```
<span bind:this={slotObj}>
        <slot />
</span>
```

Then, I can drill into the bound parent using some JavaScript and assign the slotted elements into an object called 'options':

```
let slot = slotObj.children[0];
options = slot.assignedElements();
```

If I were to console log the first element in the options object, I would see an expected:

```
console.log(options[0]); // <custom-option value="1">Option 1</custom-option>
```

I can also successfully modify attributes of elements in the options object and see the changes in the DOM. So there are no issues when it comes to "grabbing" a slotted element and changing its attributes. However, the following will **not** work from within the parent component to focus a slotted element:

```
options[0].focus();
```

This does not throw any errors, it simply does nothing that I'm able to discern. As mentioned, I am able to tab through the options, so they *are* capable of receiving focus in a regular tab scenario. It's only through the JavaScript that I seem unable to assign focus.

Any Svelte specific advice and/or general advice when dealing with custom web elements and slotted content would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Is it possible for you to put your code in the REPL? https://svelte.dev/repl

Answer (score 2):

One thing I did in the past was I made that parent tag hidden, then I grabbed all the values of the options and put them in new tags using `#each`. I put the relevant event listeners on the `#each` block's parent.

```html
App.svelte

<MultiSelect>
  <option value="MS">Malay</option>
  <option value="RU">Russian</option> 
  <option value="TH">Thai</option>
</MultiSelect>
```

```js
MultiSelect.svelte

<script>
  let slot, options = [], selected = {};
  onMount(() => {
    slot.querySelectorAll('option').forEach(o => {
      o.selected && !value.includes(o.value) && (value = [...value, o.value]);
      options = [...options, {value: o.value, name: o.textContent}]
    });
</script>

<ul class="options" on:mousedown|preventDefault={handleOptionMousedown}>
  {#each filtered as option}
    <li class:selected={selected[option.value]} class:active={activeOption === option} data-value="{option.value}">{option.name}</li>
  {/each}
</ul>

<select bind:this={slot} type="multiple" class="hidden"><slot></slot></select>
```

[Here's the link to the whole REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/c7094fb1004b440482d2a88f4d1d7ef5?version=3.17.3)

Comment: This is great. Thank you, Benny!

Comment: If you found it useful, remember to vote accordingly :)

Comment: Unfortunately, "Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."
But I have given you my vote :) Someday it will display lol

Answer (score 1):

I think Benny Hinrichs has provided an elegant solution (plus a working [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/c7094fb1004b440482d2a88f4d1d7ef5?version=3.17.3)!) that involves fewer workarounds than the below approach I found to also work.

Oddly, focusing the light DOM element (via options[0]), as described in my opening post, did not result in focus being set, *but* drilling into the shadowRoot of the light DOM element allowed me to focus a div class that wraps my option. This successfully assigned focus to one of the slotted elements, only it was the *wrong* element...

There seems to be a stack order issue (possibly specific to Svelte) because wrapping the focus in a setTimeout function (you can use 0 milliseconds) then sets focus to the correct element in the array, in this case the element in position 0 i.e. the first dropdown option in my list.

```
setTimeout(function() {
        options[0].shadowRoot.querySelector(".option-container").focus();
}, 0);
```